# Merge two photos into a single photo in python

Tags: python, image

I'm attempting to create new photos, each with 2 side by side photos taken from a list of 24 photos.  I eventually want every possible pair combination (276 total) on a new photo.  For the time being, however, I'm just trying to get the program to paste two photos onto a new photo and I'm getting an error.  The code and error are listed below:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import itertools

plist = os.listdir('image_resize')
for p in plist[:]:
    if not(p.endswith('.png')):
        plist.remove(p)
print(plist)

os.chdir('C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize')

def get_pics(x,y):
    w = os.getcwd()
    op = plist[x]
    op2 = plist[y]
    pic = Image.open(os.path.join(w,op))
    pic2 = Image.open(os.path.join(w,op2))
    pic.copy()
    pic2.copy()
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", (1280,400))
    new_image.save('conjoined_pics', format='PNG')
    pic.paste(Image.open('new_image'), (20,400,620,0))
    pic2.paste(Image.open('new_image'), (660,400,1260,0))


get_pics(0,1)       


#def get_permutations():
    #newlist = list(itertools.permutations(plist, 2))
    #print (newlist)
```

Here is the error message:

```
File not found error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'os.path.join(w,op)'
```

Comment: Hi, could you copy-paste the complete traceback to give us a bit more hindsight on the error . (as daveydave400 mentioned, it does look like you have written the string "os.path.join(w,op)" instead of the object os.path.join(w,op) without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states exactly what is wrong: the image file you are trying to open does not exist. I would try printing the value of `os.path.join(w, op)` the line before it is used and see if it makes sense.

Also, I would suggest that you change your function so it is provided either two filenames or two image objects instead of passing index values and requiring the use of global variables and requiring the environment to be in a certain directory.

**Edit:** I don't think this has to do with working with images specifically. This is probably some simple bug that you just aren't noticing. Try something like this in your function:

```
fn = os.path.join(w, op)
print(fn, os.path.exists(fn))
pic = Image.open(fn)
```

I'm looking at the error message again and it seems like you must be putting quotes around your `"os.path.join(...)"` part of the code. Is the code in your question exactly what you are running?

**Edit: Suggested Edits**

```
plist = [fn for fn in os.path.join("image_resize") if fn.endswith(".png")]

# or better, don't require the cwd or chdir by including the path
base_dir = "C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize"
plist = [os.path.join(base_dir, fn) for fn in os.listdir(base_dir) if fn.endswith(".png")]

# Or even better (this gives full paths)
from glob import glob
base_dir = "C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize"
plist = glob(os.path.join(base_dir, "*.png"))

# for the function
def get_pics(fn_in1, fn_in2):
    ... make your code work ...

get_pics(plist[0], plist[1])

# Or so that you don't have to reopen the input images *every* time they are used
def get_pics(input_image1, input_image2):
    pass

img1 = Image.open(plist[0])
img2 = Image.open(plist[1])
get_pics(img1, img2)
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?  I'm pretty new to working with images.  The files exist.  They are in the CWD.  The 'op' variable refers to the pathway where the image resides and the list is used to attach the image name to the pathway.  I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: So  'os.path.join(w,op)' = os.path.join('C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize','bridge10_RH.png') for example.  I'm using variables to avoid having to list each image in the file.

Comment: Why is python reading 'op' as 'op' rather than what the variable op refers to?

Comment: See my suggested edits in my newest update. Your problem right now is that you are not properly pointing to your image files. You need to print the result of `os.path.join(w, op)`. You have to print the actual result of this function call. If what is printed on the screen includes the words "os.path.join" you have quotes around your code that are turning it into a string and not actually *running* the code.

Comment: Here is the new error I get after adding the code you suggested:                                                                               C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize\bridge10_RH.png True
C:\Python35-32\Scripts\image_resize\bridge1_RH.png True
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'conjoined_pics'

C:\Python35-32\Scripts>

Comment: So the path exists, but for some reason, python refuses to open it.

Comment: Hm I don't do a lot of python development on Windows so I'm not sure how to help with permission errors. My guess is that since you are creating/writing to a file in the "C:\Python35-32\Scripts" directory you don't have permissions. Try writing it to somewhere in your My Documents or some where else that you have full permissions to. It's likely that your current output directory is "owned" by the system.

Comment: I read on another post that it might have something to do with trying to open a directory as a file, but I'm not sure what the solution is in that case because I've tried opening the file alone, but then python does not recognize it.

Comment: You may have missed my above comment because we posted at the same time, but try to boil this down to a simple example. Create a variable for each input filename, open those files with `Image.open`, create a variable to store the output filename, open/save to that file with `img.save(out_fn)`. Make sure that the output file doesn't exist before you save it. If you get a permission error try saving to a different directory like your my documents or something. Otherwise, I think this is all the help I can give. It is up to you to research the details.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, and maybe for testing your Python, you can make all the images *in parallel*, in a *one-liner* using **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** like this from the command-line in Terminal - assuming your  24 images are named "image????.png"

```
parallel '[ "{1}" != "{2}" ] && convert {1} {2} +append result{#}.png' ::: image* ::: image*
```

If you want to see how it works, add in `--dry-run` after `parallel` on the command-line and it will show you what it would do:

```
...
...
[ "image1.png" != "image1.png" ] && convert image1.png image1.png +append result26.png
[ "image1.png" != "image10.png" ] && convert image1.png image10.png +append result27.png
[ "image1.png" != "image11.png" ] && convert image1.png image11.png +append result28.png
[ "image1.png" != "image12.png" ] && convert image1.png image12.png +append result29.png
[ "image1.png" != "image13.png" ] && convert image1.png image13.png +append result30.png
[ "image1.png" != "image14.png" ] && convert image1.png image14.png +append result31.png
[ "image1.png" != "image15.png" ] && convert image1.png image15.png +append result32.png
[ "image1.png" != "image16.png" ] && convert image1.png image16.png +append result33.png
[ "image1.png" != "image17.png" ] && convert image1.png image17.png +append result34.png
[ "image1.png" != "image18.png" ] && convert image1.png image18.png +append result35.png
[ "image1.png" != "image19.png" ] && convert image1.png image19.png +append result36.png
[ "image1.png" != "image2.png" ] && convert image1.png image2.png +append result37.png
[ "image1.png" != "image20.png" ] && convert image1.png image20.png +append result38.png
[ "image1.png" != "image21.png" ] && convert image1.png image21.png +append result39.png
[ "image1.png" != "image22.png" ] && convert image1.png image22.png +append result40.png
[ "image1.png" != "image23.png" ] && convert image1.png image23.png +append result41.png
...
...
```